# How do I load languages into PrismJS using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, syntax-highlighting, prismjs

I am using PrismJS to add syntax highlighting to some HTML that I load into a react document. (The HTML is actually the output from a markdown converter, but it could come from anywhere.) The HTML is loaded asynchronously, sanitized, and set into a div:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: IProps) => {
  const {content} = props;
  const sanitized = marked.parse(markdown, {
    sanitizer: sanitize,
  });

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitized}} />;
};
```

I've added Prism and it works for default languages like XML or javascript.

```
export const MyComponent = (props: IProps) => {
  const {content} = props;
  const sanitized = marked.parse(markdown, {
    sanitizer: sanitize,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, [content]);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitized}} />;
};
```

However, some of the generated HTML contains Kotlin and Gradle code. I used [babel-plugin-prismjs](https://github.com/mAAdhaTTah/babel-plugin-prismjs) to add these languages:

```
plugins: [
  [
    "prismjs", {
      "languages": ["markup", "java", "kotlin",  "gradle"]
    }
  ]
]
```

However, as soon as I try to render the generated HTML, I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'prismjs/components/prism-gradle'
```

Do I need to install additional packages with yarn/npm? The page says something about an autoloader, too, but to avoid using it with that package above.